# Querying XML that has multiple sub-entities

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a basic understanding of how to query XML in SQL Server 2008+. Basic. But I am struggling to get what I want from this simple XML, and I've searched SO and the web at large for quite a while this afternoon and haven't hit upon the magic words to find help.

Given this XML:

```
declare @xml xml =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer id="12345" name="John Doe" addr1="123 Somewhere Ln" city="Riverside" state="CA">
    <Children>Jane</Children>
    <Children>John Jr.</Children>
    <Children>Susan</Children>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
<Customers>
  <Customer id="97531" name="Ben Franklin" addr1="456 Anywhere Dr" city="Albuquerque" state="NM">
    <Children>Andrew</Children>
    <Children>Adam</Children>
  </Customer>
</Customers>'
```

I can run this query and get the ids and names:

```
select cust.col.value('@id[1]','int') as id,
       cust.col.value('@name[1]','varchar(30)') as name
  from @xml.nodes('/Customers/Customer') as cust(col)

id     name
12345  John Doe
97531  Ben Franklin
```

However, what I want next is the id and name of each child, and I have not been able to figure out what's needed to get that. IOW, I want this:

```
id      child
12345   Jane
12345   John Jr.
12345   Susan
97531   Andrew
97531   Adam
```

Note that I want columnar data, not XML.

So, what is the SELECT that will give me those results from that xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your query, simply add `CROSS APPLY` on `Children` elements. Now you can select data from `Customer` as well as `Children` elements :

```
select cust.col.value('@id','int') as id,
       child.col.value('.','varchar(30)') as child
from @xml.nodes('/Customers/Customer') as cust(col)
    cross apply cust.col.nodes('Children') as child(col)
```

**output :**

```
id          child
----------- ------------------------------
12345       Jane
12345       John Jr.
12345       Susan
97531       Andrew
97531       Adam
```

Notice that `.` is used to reference current element context; and, in XML, there can't be 2 attributes of the same name in the same parent element, so indexer in `@id[1]` is not needed.

Comment: Perfect. I discovered the CROSS APPLY after some poking around I did after I posted this, but I tried everything I could think of to get the kids names with no success. I've never seen the '.' before. I get by with this stuff, but I still don't grok it. Thanks very much!

Comment: In addition to what I wrote in this answer, `.` in this case references `Children` element because it is used on `child.col`

Comment: ...and don't forget to accept this answer ([read more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just:

```
select cust.col.value('../@id','int') as id,
       cust.col.value('../@name','varchar(30)') as name,
       cust.col.value('.','varchar(30)') as child
  from @xml.nodes('/Customers/Customer/Children') as cust(col)
```

to get:

```
id      name            child
12345   John Doe        Jane
12345   John Doe        John Jr.
12345   John Doe        Susan
97531   Ben Franklin    Andrew
97531   Ben Franklin    Adam
```